# Adding another output neuron to yolo v3

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, yolo

I am using the following implementation of Yolo v3 in Keras to detect objects on a railway track with a camera mounted in front of the railway facing the tracks:

https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3

I have a data set with labelled objects and their corresponding distances in meters from the railway front. I want to use the freezed yolo weights and train the network with an additional output which is distance of the detected object.

I am using Keras 2.1.5 with python 3.5. So my question is do I need to go layer by layer in the architecture to see where do I take my output from or do I just add it in the final layer. Any help would be great.